# Maximizing entropy inside integers array

Tags: algorithm, polynomial-math, heuristics, entropy, np-complete

I have an array as follow **44477125**, and I would like to maximize the entropy so that the maximum of n-tuple be scattered.
A result example would be **74574214**.

This problem seems to be NP-Complete and I don't really have a function to measure the "entropy" of my array. (It could be the sum of distance between same numbers `entropy(44477125)=3`, `entropy(74574214)=9`)

What I'm looking for is an heuristic which could give me an acceptable result in a polynomial time.

Comment: Your present measure may result in a very ordered array (123123123). Would this be acceptable to you?

Comment: Then why not simply use a good "shuffling" algorithm (either from a library or your own)?

Comment: Actually, the array is already a randomized array. I just sorted it in my example so we can understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Algorithm

Using entropy measured as *sum of distance between same numbers*, there exists very simple polynomial-time algorithm:

1. Count number of occurrences of each number.
2. Sort pairs `< number,ocurrences >` descending by `occurrences`.
3. Create empty table of the same size as input.
4. For each pair`< number, ocurrences >`:

   a) get `maximum_possible_distance = array_size/occurrences`

   b) insert all occurrences of `number` in following indexes: `0*maximum_possible_distance, 1*maximum_possible_distance, 2*maximum_possible_distance`, etc. If index is already taken, use the nearest empty index.

### Example

Input array: 44477125

1.Counting occurrences:

<4 - 3>, <7 - 2>, <1 - 1>, <2 - 1>, <5 - 1>

2.Sorting pairs `< number - occurrences >`

It is already sorted.

3.Create empty table:

. . . . . . . .

4.Insert occurrences:

a) 1st pair <4 - 3> : `maximum_possible_distance=8/3=2`
b) insert occurrences: we have: 4..4..4.
c) 2nd pair <7 - 2> : `maximum_possible_distance=8/2=4`
d) insert occurrences: we have: 47.4.74.
e) 3rd pair <1 - 1> : `maximum_possible_distance=8/1=8`
f) insert occurrences: we have: 4714.74.
g) 4th pair <2 - 1> : `maximum_possible_distance=8/1=8`
h) insert occurrences: we have: 4714274.
i) 5th pair <5 - 1> : `maximum_possible_distance=8/1=8`
j) insert occurrences: we have: 47142745

Comment: How did I miss it... Thx ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is purely speculation, but I guess using a [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) algorithm might give good results in a reasonable time.

You'd have to create an energy criteria (something along the line of the maximum number of ntuples that you may create within you array) and try to minimize that. Remember that when using this algorithm, your choices for the initial temperature and its decrease function are very important regarding the quality of the results and the time required for the algorithm to complete.